# Recursion confusion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I hope someone can help figure out where my error lies. Calling `g 3 4 0 2 (M.empty,0) []`, I would expect `[[2,1,0,1]]` as a result. Instead, I'm seeing `[[2,1,0,1],[2,1,0,1]]`.

The program is supposed to accumulate distinct digit patterns of length `m` by adding a different digit to the list each time, returning back down when reaching `n-1` and up when reaching `0`. The apparent problem happens in the middle when the function is called recursively for both the up and down directions.

If I comment out line 11 like so:

```
else g n m (digitCount + 1) (lastDigit + 1) (hash',hashCount') (lastDigit:digits)
  -- g n m (digitCount + 1) (lastDigit - 1) (hash',hashCount') (lastDigit:digits)
```

I get the correct result `[]`

As when commenting out line 11 and modifying line 10 to:

```
else g n m (digitCount + 1) (lastDigit - 1) (hash',hashCount') (lastDigit:digits)
```

Again, a correct result `[[2,1,0,1]]`

Why when calling `g` twice using the `++` operator, I'm getting two `[2,1,0,1]`'s instead of just one? In my thinking, each result in `g` should be distinct because in any recursive call, a different order of digits is (or should be) accumulating.

Thanks in advance.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

g :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> (M.Map Int Bool, Int) -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
g n m digitCount lastDigit (hash,hashCount) digits
  | digitCount == m = if test then [reverse digits] else []
  | otherwise       =
      if lastDigit == 0
         then g n m (digitCount + 1) (lastDigit + 1) (hash',hashCount') (lastDigit:digits)
         else if lastDigit == n - 1
                 then g n m (digitCount + 1) (lastDigit - 1) (hash',hashCount') (lastDigit:digits)
                 else g n m (digitCount + 1) (lastDigit + 1) (hash',hashCount') (lastDigit:digits)
                   ++ g n m (digitCount + 1) (lastDigit - 1) (hash',hashCount') (lastDigit:digits)
 where test = hashCount == n
       (hash',hashCount') = 
         if test
            then (M.empty,hashCount)
            else case M.lookup lastDigit hash of
                   Just anyting -> (hash,hashCount)
                   Nothing      -> (M.insert lastDigit True hash,hashCount + 1)
```

Comment: I would first be explicit with your types. Are you expecting `[ [ Int ] ]`?

Comment: @ChaosPandion thanks for your comment. I added a type declaration to the code and question. Still same result and apparent error.

Comment: I spent a while writing up an answer to your other question, just to notice that it got deleted. I figure there's no reason for my effort to go to waste, so [here you go](http://pastebin.com/vfH9TnHy). Hope it's helpful.

Comment: And the [complete code](http://pastebin.com/XahvTJPL) for the previous paste, with imports and a few aesthetic cleanups but none of the commentary.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks so much Daniel for your effort, I'll look it over..roliu pointed out a mistake in my thinking about testing one vs all members (significant loss in efficiency) so i wanted to rethink the whole idea.

Comment: @DanielWagner I restored the question, so if you'd like some 'extra credit' please paste your answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why when calling g twice using the ++ operator, I'm getting two [2,1,0,1]'s instead of just 
>   one? In my thinking, each result in g should be distinct because in any recursive call, a 
>   different order of digits is (or should be) accumulating.

But your pair of (Map,Int) is the same in both calls, so the recursive calls don't know what has been found by the other call. Consider the call g ... (lastDigit-1). It will also call g ... (lastDigit) (by adding 1 to (lastDigit-1) that it got), and follow the branch g ... (lastDigit+1) to produce the same result.

Also, (Map a ()) is a (Set a), and since you don't use the Bool value from the map, it is the same as ():

```
    import qualified Data.Set as S

    g :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> (S.Set Int, Int) -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
    g n m digitCount lastDigit (hash,hashCount) digits
      | digitCount == m = if test then [reverse digits] else []
      | lastDigit < 0 || lastDigit == n  = []
      | otherwise       = g n m d' (lastDigit + 1) h' (lastDigit:digits)
                          ++ g n m d' (lastDigit - 1) h' (lastDigit:digits)
     where test = hashCount == n
           d' = digitCount + 1
           h'
            | test  = (S.empty,hashCount)
            | S.member lastDigit hash  = (hash,hashCount)
            | otherwise = (S.insert lastDigit hash,hashCount + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with set. Thank you for your answer. Consider my simple example - starts at 2, must go to 1, then branch split: (a) 212, b (210). These two branches have only one possibility next: (a) 2121 (b) 2101. At this point the test for m is true for both but the hashCount for branch a fails. The hashCount is only two. Where do you get two 2101's?

Comment: @groovy Your task is not clear, so it is difficult to say if you are doing it right. I only commented on something that looked odd, not that I understand the intention of the code very well.

Comment: @groovy here's how. let's think of calls to g' = g n m. g' 0 2 (map,0) [] calls g' 1 1 (map,1) [2] (and something else, too). This calls g' 2 0 (map,2) [1,2] (and something else, too). This calls g' 3 1 (map,3) [0,1,2] (and something else). This calls g' 4 0 (map,4) [1,0,1,2] and g' 4 2 (map,4) [1,0,1,2], both of which produce identical lists, which are concatenated.

Comment: You are correct. I think I got it now by carefully following the branches again.

Answer (score 3):

Now that you've got it working, here's a more generic approach.

We need to walk the tree of solutions.

```
    data S a = Solution a | Explore [S a]
```

Solutions are leaves of this tree, Explore are lists of options to explore.

```
    -- this is very much unfoldr-like
    generator :: [S a] -> [a]
    generator [] = []
    generator (Solution a: ss) = a: generator ss
    generator (Explore ps: ss) = generator $ ss ++ ps
```

Now, given a list of "maybe-solutions", produce a list of solutions. The generator pattern-matches Explores, and appends the list of solutions to explore to the end of the list. This way we are exploring the solutions breadth-first, and that way we can deal with non-terminating branches. (Depth-first can't get out of non-terminating branches). This of course is at expense of memory, but you can find a finite number of solutions even for problems with infinite number of solutions.

Now, the function that generates solutions for your problem:

```
    g :: Int -> Int -> [S [Int]]
    g n m = [Explore $ g' [i] (S.singleton i) | i <- [1..n-1]]  where
      g' is@(h:_) ms
       | h < 0 || h >= n || length is > m = [] --no solution, nothing to explore
       | otherwise = maybeSolution ++ 
                             [ Explore $ g' ((h-1):is) $ S.insert (h-1) ms
                             , Explore $ g' ((h+1):is) $ S.insert (h+1) ms ] 
        where
          maybeSolution
            | S.size ms == n = [Solution is]
            | otherwise      = []
```

Given n and m, produces a list of subtrees to Explore. g' is the helper function that produces a list of subtrees, given a list of Int already produced and a Set of Int already used. So, there is a definite termination condition: we appended a number outside the needed range, or the list became too long - exploring any further cannot produce Solutions, so return []. Otherwise, we are within bounds, maybeSolution sees if the list of Ints is already a valid solution, and suggests more subtrees to explore.

```
    main = print $ map reverse $ generator $ g 3 6
```

Your problem solved.

Comment: This answer really shows some of the beauty of Haskell. I'm sure that studying it will teach me more about abstracting my ideas. Thank you for explaining and demonstrating.

Answer (score 2):

In your two recursive calls to `g` combined with `(++)` in the final else branch, you are passing exactly the same parameters except for `lastDigit`.

The base case of your recursion doesn't look at `lastDigit` - it just compares `m` and `digitCount`, `n` and `hashCount` and then returns `[reverse digits]`.

So in any situation where the `(++)` case is hit immediately followed by the base case returning `[reverse digits]`, you'll get the same value repeated.

I didn't fully understand your problem specification but perhaps you need to add the "new" value for `lastDigit` to digits when you make the recursive calls - i.e. `(lastDigit-1):digits` or `(lastDigit+1):digits`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Consider my simple example - starts at 2, must go to 1, then branch split: (a) 212, b (210). These two branches have only one possibility next: (a) 2121 (b) 2101. At this point the test for `m` is true for both but the hashCount for branch  `a` fails. The hashCount is only two. Where do you get two 2101's?

Comment: You are correct. I think I got it now by carefully following the branches again. (I check-marked the other answer only because of the suggestion to use Data.Set)