# Checking collision in filename search patterns with wildcards

Tags: c#, algorithm, filenames, wildcard, collision

I need to compare file system wildcard expressions to see whether their results would overlap, by only examining/comparing the expressions.

For sake of example, we are building a utility that would sort files from one (or more locations) into a separate folders based on file system wildcard expressions. For example: *.txt goes into folder a, *.doc goes into folder b, and so on. The wildcard characters we would support would be * and ?

I want to be able to determine from just analyzing the wildcard expressions, whether they would conflict/overlap.

For example, if I have the following expressions:

```
*.x.y
*.y
```

They would conflict (overlap) because the second expression *.y would include *.x.y results. (ex. A.x.y would match both expressions)

I am approaching this by building a tree structure using the using all of the expressions, figuring that the very act of building a tree will fail if the expressions conflict.

```
For example:
*.x
a.b
a.c
b.d

might create a tree like 

         +-*-.-x
         |
start +--+
         |     +-b
         |     |
         +-a-.-+-c
         |
         |
         +-b-.-d
```

If I try to add the pattern b.x, the tree would be successful following the *.x path, and thereby say that the pattern already exists.

Am  I heading in the correct direction? Or is there an known algorithm for attacking this?

Comment: `*` means '0-to-many instances of the previous character set'. An expression beginning with `*` makes no sense.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd "file wildcard expressions" != "regex".

Comment: Can you carefully define the grammar of a legal "wildcard expression"? There are lots of different standards to choose from.

Comment: @EricLippert - just edited - hope it makes it clearer

Comment: It may make more sense to parse from the end to the beginning.  Can your expression contain multiple wildcards?  `*abc*.zip` for instance?

Comment: Yes it can contain multiple wildcards. I thought about starting at the end  too, @adamdc78, but the extension could also include wild cards. This is a tricky but fun problem!

Comment: Is the end goal of this question to find out if multiple wildcards overlap, or to sort filenames?  If the latter, the tree may be overcomplicating things; just iterate the list of wildcards for each filename and go with the first one that matches.

Comment: I don't understand how you think the process of building the tree finds you conflicts. You say that adding `b.x` follows the `*.x` path. Why? Why does it not follow the `b.d` path?  Your proposed algorithm seems to be missing some logic, but that logic will have to be turned into code somehow.  How?

Comment: @RyanBemrose the goal is to find out if multiple wildcard expressions overlap, but the wildcards are going to be used to select file(s) from locations(s) and do something with them (sorting them into directories was an example of what could be done). Bottom line is that I'm trying to verify that no two expressions would pick the same file.

Comment: @EricLippert - I think my choice of example wildcard expressions may be confusing. Maybe a better example would be *.x and ?.x. if the tree already has *.x and I walk the tree, ? could match *, so it then would compare . to ., and then compare x to x, and would reach a terminal node, and also the end of the ?.x expression. This would be a match, and would say that two expressions could yield the same result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To check whether two wildcard patterns could match the same filename, you can look at this problem as creating a grid of comparisons between pairs of characters, and then checking whether there exists a diagonal path. The illustration below shows how wildcard patterns `ab?.c??` and `a*bc.*` can be checked for possible conflict:

[image: wildcard conflict animation]

When a match between two identical literal characters is found, you move diagonally to the next characters to check. *(indicated with green arrow)*

When a literal character and a single-character wild card `?` are encountered, there are two possibilities: either the wild card matches the character (move diagonally), or the wildcard matches empty space, and you skip over it. *(indicated with purple arrows)*

When a multi-character wild card `*` is encountered, three possibilities need to be taken into account: the wild card matches an empty space before the other character, the wild card matches the other character, or the wild card matches multiple characters. *(indicated with blue arrows)*

[image: wildcard conflict comparisons]

**code example 1 (iterative)**

Below is a simple javascript implementation which iterates over the grid diagonally, marks cells which can be reached from the current cell, and then checks whether the bottom right cell is reachable. Run the code snippet to see a few examples. *(update: top-to-bottom left-to-right will do fine instead of diagonally)*

```js
function wildConflict(wild1, wild2) {
    var grid = [[true]], width = wild1.length, height = wild2.length;
    for (var x = 1; x <= width; x++) grid[x] = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            if (grid[x][y]) {
                var a = wild1.charAt(x), b = wild2.charAt(y);
                if (a == '*' || b == '*' || a == '?' || b == '?' || a == b) grid[x + 1][y + 1] = true;
                if (a == '*' || b == '*' || a == '?') grid[x + 1][y] = true;
                if (a == '*' || b == '*' || b == '?') grid[x][y + 1] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return grid[width][height] == true;
}

var a = ["a", "a", "a*", "abc", "a*", "*.x.y", "*.x.y", "a*b*", "a*bc.*", "a?c.de"];
var b = ["a", "b", "abc", "a?", "*b", "*.y", "*.x", "a*c*", "ab?.c??", "ac.d??"];
for (var i in a) document.write("&quot;" + a[i] + "&quot; &harr; &quot;" + b[i] + "&quot; &rarr; " + wildConflict(a[i], b[i]) + "<BR>");
```

**code example 2 (recursive)**

A simple recursive implementation has the drawback of potentially checking some character pairs more than once. It doesn't need the 2D-array, but the recursions obviously use memory too.

Note that when a multi-character wild card `*`is encountered, the algorithm recurses with only two possibilities: jump over the one character, or jump over the other character; jumping over both characters (i.e. the wild card matches exactly one character) is taken care of in the next step, when the wild card is compared to the next character.

```js
function wildConflict(wild1, wild2) {
    var w1 = wild1.split(''), w2 = wild2.split('');
    return conflict(0, 0);

    function conflict(p1, p2) {
        if (p1 == w1.length || p2 == w2.length) {
            if ((p1 == w1.length && p2 == w2.length)
            || (p1 == w1.length - 1 && (w1[p1] == '*' || w1[p1] == '?'))
            || (p2 == w2.length - 1 && (w2[p2] == '*' || w2[p2] == '?'))) {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;                            // premature end
        }
        else if (w1[p1] == '*' || w2[p2] == '*' || (w1[p1] == '?' && w2[p2] == '?')) {
            return conflict(p1 + 1, p2) || conflict(p1, p2 + 1);
        }
        else if (w1[p1] == '?') {
            return conflict(p1 + 1, p2) || conflict(p1 + 1, p2 + 1);
        }
        else if (w2[p2] == '?') {
            return conflict(p1, p2 + 1) || conflict(p1 + 1, p2 + 1);
        }
        else if (w1[p1] == w2[p2]) {
            return conflict(p1 + 1, p2 + 1);
        }
        else return false;                               // unequal literals
    }
}

var x = ["a", "a", "a*", "abc", "a*", "*.x.y", "*.x.y", "a*b*", "a*bc.*", "a?c.de"];
var y = ["a", "b", "abc", "a?", "*b", "*.y", "*.x", "a*c*", "ab?.c??", "ac.d??"];
for (var i in x) document.write("&quot;" + x[i] + "&quot; &harr; &quot;" + y[i] + "&quot; &rarr; " + wildConflict(x[i], y[i]) + "<BR>");
```

Comment: @m69 - How did you make that nice animation?

Comment: @Enigmativity A combination of Photoshop and too much time on my hands. You just select which layers to show for each frame, and save as an animated gif.

Comment: @m69 - Thank you so much! Marked as answer. You really went above and beyond with this, and we appreciate it very much!

Comment: @RickHodder You're welcome. I like to practise writing algorithms with SO questions. Would you mind if I added the tags `filename` `wild-card` and `collision` to the question, and maybe edited the title to mention wild cards and filenames?

Comment: @m69 - that would be great. By the way, do you have any suggestions for reading on algorithms that you found helpful?

Comment: @RickHodder Unfortunately, as I've had no formal training in programming, I can't really recommend any books. I trawl SO for interesting questions, and then try to find a solution by myself, rather than systematically studying algorithms. When other users start talking about turning wildcards into finite automata, I have to Google to know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Turn each wildcard expression into a finite automaton that matches it.

Compute the intersection of the finite automatons.

Use dynamic programming to see whether the intersection can ever match.

If you don't recognize these concepts, see [Algorithm for exclusion of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314077/algorithm-for-exclusion-of-numbers/11317787#11317787) for an attempt of mine to explain it a few years ago.  (At that point for counting things that matched a collection of regular expressions, but the principles are identical.)

Comment: This is certainly how I'd do it, but I don't think you need dynamic programming to notice that the intersection is empty. :) (Of course, there is the exponential blowup problem, as exemplified by the pattern `*a........................b`)

Comment: The exponential blowup problem is irritating.  The right solution to solving it is probably to make states be single spots in the match, and do an NFA engine rather than a DFA one.  Then do a search for all pairs of states that the "intersection NFA" engine could wind up in.  This will be no worse than quadratic.

Comment: sgtm. Even so, I think an empty intersection will reveal itself by there not being any way to reach an accepting state.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to turn the patterns into regular expressions and then see if they match eachother?  Solution here is based on [the rules for Directory.GetFiles on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) -- I feel like there's **SOMETHING** wrong with it but I'm not sure what.

here's a basic implementation

```
    private bool Equivalent(string patternOne, string patternTwo)
    {
        // convert both patterns to regexes based on rules for Directory.GetFiles
        var expressionOne = FilePatternToRegex(patternOne);
        var expressionTwo = FilePatternToRegex(patternTwo);

        // if either regex matches the opposite pattern, we've got a conflict
        return expressionTwo.IsMatch(patternOne) || expressionOne.IsMatch(patternTwo);
    }

    Regex FilePatternToRegex(string pattern)
    {
        // separate extension and filename
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(pattern);
        var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pattern);

        // escape filename
        filename = EscapeFilePattern(filename);

        // 3 character extensions are a special case -- should be greedy eg xls matches xlsx
        // extension.Length == 4 bc its dot AND 3 characters
        if (extension.Length == 4 && !extension.Contains("*") && !extension.Contains("?"))
        {
            extension = extension + ".*";
        }
        else
        {
            // all other extension lengths just get escaped like normal regexes
            extension = EscapeFilePattern(extension);
        }

        // our final pattern should also only match at the string start/end
        var finalPattern = "\\A" + filename + extension + "\\z";

        return new Regex(finalPattern);
    }

    string EscapeFilePattern(string pattern)
    {
        // escape star and question mark bc they are filepattern significant
        pattern = pattern.Replace("*", "%S%").Replace("?", "%Q%");

        // escape all other special regex characters
        pattern = Regex.Escape(pattern);

        // turn star and question mark into their regex equivalents
        pattern = pattern.Replace("%S%", ".+").Replace("%Q%", ".");

        return pattern;
    }
```

**EDIT**: based on further discussion in comments, this is broken.  Proof using code sample that it's broken:

```
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).CreateSubdirectory(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        var path = Path.Combine(dir.FullName, "abc");

        File.WriteAllText(path, "*");

        // verify both patterns match our file
        Assert.AreEqual(path, dir.GetFiles("a*c*")[0].FullName);
        Assert.AreEqual(path, dir.GetFiles("a*b*")[0].FullName);

        // current regex based solution thinks they are NOT equivalent 
        // when they are
        Assert.IsFalse(Equivalent("a*c*", "a*b*"));
```

Comment: Thanks Josh - I'll give that a shot!

Comment: This doesn't work for a variety of reasons. Most importantly, the fact that two regexes R1 and R2 match the same string S does not imply that either R1 matches R2 as a string or vice versa. As a simple example, `(a|b)*` and `[ab]*` are identical regexes, but neither can match the other one. Also, your function to create regexes does not take regex metacharacters into account, so it will fail if the pattern contains any such character; it would need to be escaped.

Comment: @rici note the EscapeFilePattern method being called in FilePatternToRegex does take regex characters into account via Regex.Escape.  You are correct about one regex pattern matching the other not meaning the two will neccessarily match the same results, but this solution explicitly ignores most features of regular expressions, and the inputs we're expecting are filepatterns eg a?bc*.xyz

Comment: @joshua: ok, it does do escaping. Sorry. But I still don't think you can count on a regex matching a pattern. `a*b*` and `a*c*` both match `abc` but neither matches the other one.

Comment: @rici ooooooooooooh ok hey thats good.  thats what i was trying to pinpoint, idk why i didnt see that.  yeah, this solution is broken.  it works for a lot of cases, but thats ^ def an example.  thank you