# File mask conflicts

Tags: java, file, masking

I am looking for a nice way to find out whether two file masks are getting into conflict or not.

Background:

My application can have several file scanners. Each file scanner can be setup with one directory and one or more file masks (`*.xml`, `*test.txt`, ...)

If I add a second scanner to the same directory I want my application to check for any conflicts.

Example

```
Scanner A: /home/tmp   *.txt
Scanner B: /home/tmp   *test.xml
```

This would work without any problems. But if I add another scanner

```
Scanner C: /home/tmp   *.xml
```

then it will be conflicted with Scanner B. But how can I check this with Java?

Is there a nicer way?

Comment: Write a class that encapsulates a directory and pattern, give it proper `equals` and `hashCode` methods, and keep a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of instances of that class.  It would help if you showed the code you have written so far.

Comment: I mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009784/checking-collision-in-filename-search-patterns-with-wildcards only in JAVA

Comment: The question to which you’ve linked has a thorough answer that seems to do what you want.  Are you asking how to translate JavaScript code into Java code?