# Code Jam String Matching

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

We are giving two Patterns.A pattern consists of only uppercase/lowercase English alphabet letters and stars (*). 
A star can match between `zero and four` letters.
 
For example,  GoneGirl and GoneTomorrow matches the pattern Gone**, but books with the titles TheGoneGirl, and GoneWithTheWind cannot.
 [Question Link](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/8284486/dashboard#s=p1)

We have to find out if There is string matched matches two patterns.

MY Approach:
Dynamic Programming maintain a 2d array.

```
 M[0][0]=true;

for(int i=1;i<=S.length();i++){

for(int j=1;j<=A.length();j++){

      if(!M[i-1][j-1]) continue;

      if(S.charAt(i-1)=='*'){

            for(int k=0;k<4;k++) M[i][j+k]=true;

            M[i][j-1]=true;
      }

      if(A.charAt(j-1)=='*'){

          for(int k=0;k<4;k++) M[i+k][j]=true;

          M[i-1][j]=true;
      }

      if(S.charAt(i-1)==A.charAt(j-1)) M[i][j]=true;


}
```

Can someone help me what wrong in my algorithm ?

Comment: The first step should be to find a test case that fails.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009784/checking-collision-in-filename-search-patterns-with-wildcards/

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems almost correct. But, consider this example -

```
A = "*"
B = "****"
```

Here you make `dp[1][1] = dp[1][2] = dp[1][3] = dp[1][4] = true` but for each `*` in `B`, there can be another 4 `*`s, in total 16 stars. Your program won't work in that case.

A safe approach is to pre-process the strings by replacing each `*` with 4 `*` before doing the DP calculation. Then for each `*`, you can either match one letter or skip. I got accepted by this approach.