# Checking if two patterns match one another?

Tags: regex, algorithm

[This Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/regular-expression-matching/#/description) is about how to match a pattern string against a text string as efficiently as possible. The pattern string can consists of letters, dots, and stars, where a letter only matches itself, a dot matches any individual character, and a star matches any number of copies of the preceding character. For example, the pattern

```
ab*c.
```

would match `ace` and `abbbbcc`. I know that it's possible to solve this original problem using dynamic programming.

My question is whether it's possible to see whether two *patterns* match one another. For example, the pattern

```
bdbaa.*
```

can match

```
bdb.*daa
```

Is there a nice algorithm for solving this pattern-on-pattern matching problem?

Comment: Can you please provide more details, or reformulate the question I can not really understand it. Do you ask if you can match a pattern with a pattern instead of pattern with string?

Comment: @Keloo yes, that is what I mean

Comment: Similar question about filenames with wildcards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009784/checking-collision-in-filename-search-patterns-with-wildcards/34011424#34011424

Comment: @codecrazer: I have came up with one algorithm. Can you provide few test cases which you feel might be corner ones? I will post my answer as well after testing them and include those test results too in my answer. Please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean that the two regexps match the same set of strings, or that there's a string that's matched by both?

Comment: Is this *Checking if given two patterns there exists at least one string matched by both?* (in the example, there are strings like `bdbaadaa` that are matched by both `bdbaa.*` and `bdb.*daa` (described by `bdbaa.*daa`)) or *Checking if given two patterns `a` and `b`,  `a` matches `b` as well as  `b` matches `a`?* (neither of which holds in the example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on my idea of DP and came out with the below implementation of the above problem. Please feel free to edit the code in case someone finds any test cases failed. From my side, I tried few test cases and passed all of them, which I will be mentioning below as well.

**Please note that I have extended the idea which is used to solve the `regex` pattern matching with a string using DP. To refer to that idea, please refer to the LeetCode link provided in the OP and look out for discussion part. They have given the explanation for `regex` matching and the string.**

The idea is to create a dynamic memoization table, entries of which will follow the below rules:

1. If pattern1[i] == pattern2[j], dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1]
2. If pattern1[i] == '.' or pattern2[j] == '.', then dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1]
3. The trick lies here: If pattern1[i] = '*', then if dp[i-2][j] exists, then
   dp[i][j] = dp[i-2][j] || dp[i][j-1] else dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-1].
4. If pattern2[j] == '*', then if pattern1[i] == pattern2[j-1], then 
   dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-2] || dp[i-1][j] 
   else dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-2]

`pattern1` goes row-wise and `pattern2` goes column-wise. Also, please note that this code should also work for normal regex pattern matching with any given string. I have verified it by running it on LeetCode and it passed all the available test cases there!

Below is the complete working implementation of the above logic:

```
boolean matchRegex(String pattern1, String pattern2){
    boolean dp[][] = new boolean[pattern1.length()+1][pattern2.length()+1];
    dp[0][0] = true;
            //fill up for the starting row
    for(int j=1;j<=pattern2.length();j++){
        if(pattern2.charAt(j-1) == '*')
            dp[0][j] = dp[0][j-2];

    }
            //fill up for the starting column
    for(int j=1;j<=pattern1.length();j++){
        if(pattern1.charAt(j-1) == '*')
            dp[j][0] = dp[j-2][0];

    }

            //fill for rest table
    for(int i=1;i<=pattern1.length();i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=pattern2.length();j++){
                        //if second character of pattern1 is *, it will be equal to 
                        //value in top row of current cell
                        if(pattern1.charAt(i-1) == '*'){
                            dp[i][j] = dp[i-2][j] || dp[i][j-1];
                        }

                        else if(pattern1.charAt(i-1)!='*' && pattern2.charAt(j-1)!='*' 
                                    && (pattern1.charAt(i-1) == pattern2.charAt(j-1) 
                                    || pattern1.charAt(i-1)=='.' || pattern2.charAt(j-1)=='.'))
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1];
                        else if(pattern2.charAt(j-1) == '*'){
                boolean temp = false;
                if(pattern2.charAt(j-2) == pattern1.charAt(i-1) 
                                            || pattern1.charAt(i-1)=='.' 
                                            || pattern1.charAt(i-1)=='*' 
                                            || pattern2.charAt(j-2)=='.') 

                    temp = dp[i-1][j];
                dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-2] || temp;

            }
        }
    }
            //comment this portion if you don't want to see entire dp table
            for(int i=0;i<=pattern1.length();i++){
                for(int j=0;j<=pattern2.length();j++)
                    System.out.print(dp[i][j]+" ");
                System.out.println("");
            }
    return dp[pattern1.length()][pattern2.length()];
}
```

Driver method:

```
System.out.println(e.matchRegex("bdbaa.*", "bdb.*daa"));

Input1: bdbaa.* and bdb.*daa
Output1: true

Input2: .*acd and .*bce
Output2: false

Input3: acd.* and .*bce
Output3: true
```

Time complexity: `O(mn)` where `m` and `n` are lengths of two regex patterns given. Same will be the space complexity.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where this comes from and what the intuition is?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Sure. Whenever we encounter a `.` we need to match it with any character. That means we can have the value found in `dp` table *excluding* the current characters being compared. When we encounter a `*`, we can either have no occurrence of previous character found or we can have more than one occurence of the previous character present. In this case, if character is found, we need to look at 2 teps back in current table for same row.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Continuing on previous comment, if we encounter more than one occurrence of the previous element, that means we need to have a match between current character in one of the patterns and the previous character of the other pattern. If that is a match, we take the top of the cell value for current cell. And then take `||` of both the values found so far. For more details, please refer the discussion section of the same LeetCode problem. They have provided it for regex and string matching. I just extended same idea for both regex patterns.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I hope I am clear on this? Please let me know if you have any doubts regarding this solution.

Comment: Those who are downvoting the accepted answer, at least have a courtesy to give reasons for downvoting. This is really immature to do so without any reasoning.

Comment: Probably because they think other answers are better, although I see nothing disqualifying this one, explanation and code is there. Btw. any correct solution to the question asked should pass all test cases, it is a generalization of the leetcode problem.

Comment: @maraca Other answers are better- that's not a reason to downvote other correct answers at all. If one feels that this is not better answer, just don't downvote it, right? And what do you mean by "any correct solution should pass all test cases?" Have you found any test that doesn't pass with this code? Please let me know.

Comment: @CodeHunter Wasn't me who downvoted it, I am just stating that there is no reason to write "passed" bold, because it is not really surprising and it only shows that a subset of the problem is solved correctly and doesn't prove anything about the generalization by codecrazer.

Comment: @maraca: I never meant you downvoted! Chill! I just wanted to know if you found any test case failed so that I can look into it to make the code better. No hard feelings about that! :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach that works in polynomial time. It's slightly heavyweight and there may be a more efficient solution, though.

The first observation that I think helps here is to reframe the problem. Rather than asking whether these patterns match *each other*, let's ask this equivalent question:

> Given patterns P1 and P2, is there a string w where P1 and P2 each match w?

In other words, rather than trying to get the two patterns to match one another, we'll search for a string that each pattern matches.

You may have noticed that the sorts of patterns you're allowed to work with are a subset of the regular expressions. This is helpful, since there's a pretty elaborate theory of what you can do with regular expressions and their properties. So rather than taking aim at your original problem, let's solve this even more general one:

> Given two regular expressions R1 and R2, is there a string w that both R1 and R2 match?

The reason for solving this more general problem is that it enables us to use the theory that's been developed around regular expressions. For example, in formal language theory we can talk about the *language of a regular expression*, which is the set of all strings that the regex matches. We can denote this L(R). If there's a string that's matched by two regexes R1 and R2, then that string belongs to both L(R1) and L(R2), so our question is equivalent to

> Given two regexes R1 and R2, is there a string w in L(R1) ∩ L(R2)?

So far all we've done is reframe the problem we want to solve. Now let's go solve it.

The key step here is that it's possible to convert any regular expression into an NFA (a nondeterministic finite automaton) so that every string matched by the regex is accepted by the NFA and vice-versa. Even better, the resulting NFA can be constructed in polynomial time. So let's begin by constructing NFAs for each input regex.

Now that we have those NFAs, we want to answer this question: is there a string that both NFAs accept? And fortunately, there's a quick way to answer this. There's a common construction on NFAs called the *product construction* that, given two NFAs N1 and N2, constructs a new NFA N' that accepts all the strings accepted by both N1 and N2 and no other strings. Again, this construction runs in polynomial time.

Once we have N', we're basically done! All we have to do is run a breadth-first or depth-first search through the states of N' to see if we find an accepting state. If so, great! That means there's a string accepted by N', which means that there's a string accepted by both N1 and N2, which means that there's a string matched by both R1 and R2, so the answer to the original question is "yes!" And conversely, if we can't reach an accepting state, then the answer is "no, it's not possible."

I'm certain that there's a way to do all of this implicitly by doing some sort of implicit BFS over the automaton N' without actually constructing it, and it should be possible to do this in something like time O(n<sup>2</sup>). If I have some more time, I'll revisit this answer and expand on how to do that.

Comment: Your answer is really good, but I need implementation, so I don't give bounty to your solution. I upvote your solution and really thanks for your idea on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dynamic approach tailored to this subset of a [Thompson NFA](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) style regex implementing only `.` and `*`:

You can do that either with dynamic programming (here in Ruby):

```
def is_match(s, p)
    return true if s==p 
    len_s, len_p=s.length, p.length
    dp=Array.new(len_s+1) { |row| [false] * (len_p+1) }
    dp[0][0]=true 
    (2..len_p).each { |j| dp[0][j]=dp[0][j-2] && p[j-1]=='*' }

    (1..len_s).each do |i|
        (1..len_p).each do |j|
           if p[j-1]=='*' 
               a=dp[i][j - 2]
               b=[s[i - 1], '.'].include?(p[j-2])
               c=dp[i - 1][j]
               dp[i][j]= a || (b && c)   
           else
               a=dp[i - 1][j - 1]
               b=['.', s[i - 1]].include?(p[j - 1])
               dp[i][j]=a && b
           end 
        end
    end
    dp[len_s][len_p]      
end    
# 139 ms on Leetcode
```

Or recursively:

```
def is_match(s,p,memo={["",""]=>true})
    if p=="" && s!="" then return false end
    if s=="" && p!="" then return p.scan(/.(.)/).uniq==[['*']] && p.length.even? end
    if memo[[s,p]]!=nil then return memo[[s,p]] end

    ch, exp, prev=s[-1],p[-1], p.length<2 ? 0 : p[-2]
    a=(exp=='*' && (
           ([ch,'.'].include?(prev) && is_match(s[0...-1], p, memo) || 
                                       is_match(s, p[0...-2], memo))))
    b=([ch,'.'].include?(exp) && is_match(s[0...-1], p[0...-1], memo))
    memo[[s,p]]=(a || b)
end
# 92 ms on Leetcode
```

In each case:

1. The operative starting point in the string and pattern is at the second character looking for `*` and matches one character back for as long as `s` matches the character in `p` prior to the `*`
2. The meta character `.` is being used as a fill in for the actual character. This allows any character in `s` to match `.` in `p`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with backtracking too, not very efficiently (because the match of the same substrings may be recalculated many times, which could be improved by introducing a lookup table where all non-matching pairs of strings are saved and the calculation only happens when they cannot be found in the lookup table), but seems to work (js, the algorithm assumes the simple regex are valid, which means not beginning with * and no two adjacent * [[try it yourself]](https://jsfiddle.net/hsso0tt7/)):

```js
function canBeEmpty(s) {
    if (s.length % 2 == 1)
        return false;
    for (let i = 1; i < s.length; i += 2)
        if (s[i] != "*")
            return false;
    return true;
}

function match(a, b) {
    if (a.length == 0 || b.length == 0)
        return canBeEmpty(a) && canBeEmpty(b);
    let x = 0, y = 0;
    // process characters up to the next star
    while ((x + 1 == a.length || a[x + 1] != "*") &&
           (y + 1 == b.length || b[y + 1] != "*")) {
        if (a[x] != b[y] && a[x] != "." && b[y] != ".")
            return false;
        x++; y++;
        if (x == a.length || y == b.length)
            return canBeEmpty(a.substr(x)) && canBeEmpty(b.substr(y));
    }
    if (x + 1 < a.length && y + 1 < b.length && a[x + 1] == "*" && b[y + 1] == "*")
        // star coming in both strings
        return match(a.substr(x + 2), b.substr(y)) || // try skip in a
               match(a.substr(x), b.substr(y + 2)); // try skip in b
    else if (x + 1 < a.length && a[x + 1] == "*") // star coming in a, but not in b
        return match(a.substr(x + 2), b.substr(y)) || // try skip * in a
               ((a[x] == "." || b[y] == "." || a[x] == b[y]) && // if chars matching
                      match(a.substr(x), b.substr(y + 1))); // try skip char in b
    else // star coming in b, but not in a
        return match(a.substr(x), b.substr(y + 2)) || // try skip * in b
               ((a[x] == "." || b[y] == "." || a[x] == b[y]) && // if chars matching
                      match(a.substr(x + 1), b.substr(y))); // try skip char in a
}
```

For a little optimization you could normalize the strings first:

```js
function normalize(s) {
    while (/([^*])\*\1([^*]|$)/.test(s) || /([^*])\*\1\*/.test(s)) {
        s = s.replace(/([^*])\*\1([^*]|$)/, "$1$1*$2"); // move stars right
        s = s.replace(/([^*])\*\1\*/, "$1*"); // reduce
    }
    return s;
}
// example: normalize("aa*aa*aa*bb*b*cc*cd*dd") => "aaaa*bb*ccc*ddd*"
```

There is a further reduction of the input possible: `x*.*` and `.*x*` can both be replaced by `.*`, so to get the maximal reduction you would have to try to move as many stars as possible next to `.*` (so moving some stars to the left can be better than moving all to the right).

Answer (score -2):

IIUC, you are asking:  "Can a regex pattern match another regex pattern?"

Yes, it can. Specifically, `.` matches "any character" which of course includes `.` and `*`. So if you have a *string* like this:

```
bdbaa.*
```

How could you match it? Well, you could match it like this:

```
bdbaa..
```

Or like this:

```
b.*
```

Or like:

```
.*ba*.*
```

Comment: I found that I made bad interpretation of my thought, I knew that a pattern can be matched with another pattern, but what I want to ask is that are we able to determine a pattern can be matched with another pattern.